# Best practice for adding additional variables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In short: I want to print out a list of contacts, but at a label new in the title if the contact was created this month.

In a framework like Laravel, you have 3 places to implement that: model, view or controller.

At the moment I have the following check in my view:

```
@if ( $value->created_at->diff( new DateTime('today'))->format('%a') < 30 )
     <span class="label label-success m-r-10 pull-left">NEW</span>
@endif
```

But I'm not happy with to much logic in my views, since I have external front-end developers.

A complex Elequent query in my model is also not the right way to do it.

And in my Controller I have:

```
public function index()
{
    //get all contacts
    $contacts = Contact::with('organizations')->get();

    //load the view and pass the results
    return View::make('contact.index')
                 ->with('contacts', $contacts);
}
```

But then I need to loop the whole contacts array to check every item and set an extra variable if it is a new contact.

What is the best and cleanest way to implement such checks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel already has a native way to add custom attributes to your models. In your model, use the `$appends` property together with an accessor function to add the `is_new` attribute to your model instances.

```php
// ========= models/Contact.php
class Contact extends Eloquent {

    protected $appends = array('is_new');

    public function getIsNewAttribute()
    {
        return $this->created_at->diff( new DateTime('today'))->format('%a') < 30;
    }

}

// ========= views/contact/index.blade.php

@if ($value->is_new)
<span class="label label-success m-r-10 pull-left">NEW</span>
@endif
```

For more info see the bottom of http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

Comment: I love this solution! Couldn't find any documentation about the naming conventions between array('is_new') and  getIsNewAttribute()

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to create a helper function which can be called each time you want to print the title.

Create a `helpers.php` file

```
// app/helpers.php
function contact_title($contact)
{
    if ($contact->created_at->diff( new DateTime('today'))->format('%a') < 30)
    {
        return $contact->title . ' <span class="your-classes">NEW</span>';
    }

    return $contact->title;
}
```

You now need to make sure the helpers file gets loaded.

```
// add this line to app/start/global.php
require app_path().'/helpers.php';
```

Now in your view you can just have the following

```
...
{{ contact_title($value) }}
...
```